# Accessing the Data of an RLink RDataFrame

Tags: data-structures, rlink, version-9

I am trying to extract the data table itself from an RLink-generated RDataFrame:

```
Needs["RLink`"];
InstallR[];
REvaluate["require(datasets);"];
REvaluate["data(airquality);"]
airquality = REvaluate["as.data.frame(airquality)"]
```

[image: RDataFrame Output]

but now I would like to extract out the goodies like RNames and RData so that I may work with them independently.  (BTW, TableForm on an RDataFrame is *awesome*!)

I tried messing around with its InputForm, but I got stuck. How do I extract RNames, RData, etc. into standard *Mathematica* lists?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Short answer

From the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/RLink/tutorial/DataTypes.html) - example

```
df=REvaluate["
   {
      age <- 18:23
      height <- c(76.1,77,78.1,78.2,78.8,79.7)
      name <- c(\"John Young\",\"Jane Ty\",\"john Ed\",\"Mary Ann\",\"Thomas Ed\",\"John Wood\")
      village <- data.frame(age=age,height=height,name=name)
      as.data.frame(village)
   }
"]

(*
    RDataFrame[RNames[age,height,name],RData[{18,19,20,21,22,23}, 
         {76.1,77.,78.1,78.2,78.8,79.7},RFactor[{4,1,2,5,6,3},
         RFactorLevels[Jane Ty,john Ed,John Wood,John Young,Mary Ann,Thomas Ed]]],
         RRowNames[1,2,3,4,5,6]
    ] 
*)
```

Now,

```
RGetData[df]

(*
   {{18,19,20,21,22,23}, 76.1,77.,78.1,78.2,78.8,79.7},
   RFactor[{4,1,2,5,6,3},RFactorLevels[Jane Ty,john Ed,John Wood,John Young,
      Mary Ann,Thomas Ed]]}
*)
```

This extracts the names.

```
RGetNames[df]

(*  {age,height,name}   *)
```

This extracts the row names.

```
RGetRowNames[df]

(*  {1,2,3,4,5,6} *)
```

### Long answer

`RDataFrame` (as well as `RFactor`) are two data types implemented via `RLink` type extension mechanism. In this sense, there is no difference between them being implemented by the RLink developer, or the user. The relevant tutorial is [R Data types in RLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/RLink/tutorial/DataTypes.html), the second large section on type extension mechanism. It contains a detailed walk-through for the procedure of defining new types.

The support for data frames and factors currently is very basic. Basically, apart from a few simple data transformations and display functions, such as `TableForm`, not much is in there. In time, this support will probably become better, but you don't have to wait until then - you can implement your own extensions or extend those implementations. The full source code for `RDataFrame` and `RFactor` implementation is available at

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory,"SystemFiles","Links","RLink","Kernel","DataTypes","Base.m"}]
```

To answer your specific question, the relevant part of this implementation for a data frame looks like

```
RDataFrame /: RGetNames[ RDataFrame[RNames[names___],__]] := {names};

RDataFrame /: RGetAttributes[ RDataFrame[__,a : (_RAttributes | None) : None]]:=
   RGetAllAttributes[a];


RDataFrame /: 
  RGetRowNames[
     RDataFrame[
         _,
         RData[data__],
         rnames : (RRowNames[rn__] | Automatic) : Automatic,
         a : (RAttributes[__] | None) : None
     ]]:=
   If[rnames === Automatic, Range[Length[{data}]],{rn}];

RDataFrame /: RGetData[RDataFrame[_, RData[data__],___]]:= {data};
```

which both tells you how to extract the data parts (which heads are responsible for this), and how this has been implemented. That's all there is to it currently. The data extractors like `RGetNames`, `RGetAttributes`, `RGetData`, `RGetRowNames` are universal heads which are overloaded by various data types, and currently placed at

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory,"SystemFiles","Links","RLink","Kernel","DataTypes","Common.m"}]
```

The overloading for specific data types is done via `UpValues`,  which is *the* recommended way to do this for user-defined types. This way such implementations will be independent for 2 different users.

How these data extractor heads work for data frames is illustrated in the mentioned tutorial. If you want to extend the current functionality, you have two choices: either create a package that would extend the current functionality, or unregister current implementations of `RDataFrame` etc via `RDataTypeUnregister` function and create a package with your own implementations, which would replace the existing ones and which you can inform `Rlink` about via the `"AddToRDataTypePath"` option (which is accepted by both `InstallR` and `RDataTypeDefinitionsReload` - the latter being a specific tool to enable to to pick up new definitions from files without quitting the RLink session).

It has been discussed in chat already that it would be nice to have a way to share such new data type implementations between RLink users. All I can say at the moment is that work is underway to enable that.

Comment: ...and with this answer, I just kicked my Emacs/StarterKit/org-mode/ESS/pgfSweave/ggplot2 "Frankenstein monster" to the curb.

Comment: @EricBrown Thanks for the accept:). I updated it with explicit example taken from the docs.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I believe you are the developer for `RLink`. I have a question regarding `RLink`. I can see that your framework has a way of showing the internal representation of R in Mathematica using symbolic wrappers. Does your framework's representation of R's internal representation completely true about how R represents it natively or have you made some simplifications or some generalizations? In other words, I can use your framework to understand how R works internally?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Also please suggest some book or text which covers the details about R language's core data structures, the language, and its evaluation model. All I can find are books about how to use it for data science etc. Nothing that goes in-depth like the internal representations shown in your framework. Also from your knowledge about R, does it has a consistent structure like Mathematica's everything is an expression?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I believe in the upcoming version `R` will be available via `ExternalLanguage` functionality. Does that mean the current `RLink` will be depreciated? Also will you link `R`'s `data.frame` to Mathematica's `Dataset` like python's `pandas` dataset now automatically get turned into Mathematica's `Dataset`? Also does Mathematica's `Association` have a direct analog in `R`?

Comment: @user13892 Regarding your first question: the representation is definitely simplified, since not all data types and structures of R are faithfully represented on Mathematica's side when we import some object from R into Mathematica. That said, most core objects I believe are faithfully represented. If you want to understand R internally, however, you should study proper R, not RLink. You can do this via RLink from within Mathematica, but you will still need to study R.

Comment: @user13892 Regarding the literature. I have not been following recent additions / new books for R for a number of years. I can recommend [The Art of R Programming](https://www.amazon.com/Art-Programming-Statistical-Software-Design/dp/1593273843) by Norman Matloff and [Advanced R](https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Second-Chapman-Hall-CRC/dp/0815384572) by Hadley Wickham.

Comment: @user13892 Re: ExternalLanguage - it will be using RLink underneath. Re: Associations - I believe not, since they are immutable. But otherwise, basic objects in R can be considered dictionaries, or if you want something more specialized, you can use packages, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818970/is-there-a-dictionary-functionality-in-r) for example. Re: Dataset: it should be hard to do that on your own. Also, RLink has the type extension system, which allows one to automate such conversions. It is documented.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin thank you for all the answers! Few more things. Is there an analog of `Mathematica`'s `FullForm` or `RLink`'s `ToRForm` in `R`. That would make studying `R` from within `R` very easy. Also what your framework calls general `RObject`, how can I access it from within `R`? Also, my questions are very trivial is because I have only used `R` as an application and not as a language.

Comment: @user13892 Re: FullForm : have a look at [deparse](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/deparse.html). Re: RObject - this is a generic wrapper for general R object which does not fit into one of the basic types (for example because it has additional attributes). Hope this helps. In general, if you have further questions, please formulate and ask them as a standalone ones on the site.